# Getting a captcha for opening two search bookmarks

Tags: support, captcha

Last month I asked: [Should I be worried about how fast I use the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332078/392799)

I'm pleased to announce I got my first captcha.

[image]

This is just a feedback, for perhaps altering the algorithm behind it if at all possible.

What triggered it is opening two bookmarks at once, both are search results, one of which is `is:a created:2d..`, which is sorted by new. My rationale for that is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330351/392799).

Update: I was able to reproduce it. Middle-clicking the folder with the 2 bookmarks brought up the captcha for the second tab.